# Grep file search returns: Is a directory in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, file, terminal, grep, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to search for a specific file using the example [How do I use grep command to search a file?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/)

Trying `grep searchingforfile /Users/myuser/path/to/dir` returns:

> grep: /Users/myuser/path/to/dir: Is a directory

Please let me know what is the best way to search for  a file then in this case.

Comment: If it is a dir, then you might want to grep all the files inside it with `grep  searchingforfile /Users/myuser/path/to/dir/*`

Comment: Using this gives me the same Is a directory error response for all the directories under it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to find files which begin with `f` in the current directory:

```
ls f*
```

If you want to find files ending with "jpg" in the current directory and all directories below:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -print
```

If you want filenames containing pattern in current directory and below:

```
find . -type f -name "pattern" -print
```

but put an asterisk either side of the pattern (I can't do it on here)

Or, if your pattern is more complicated

```
find . -type f -print | grep "someFunkyPattern"
```

If you want to search for pattern in a file called `fred`:

```
grep pattern fred
```

If you want to search for `bill` or `steve` in files called `friends1` and `friends2` and you don't care about case (capital letters) use the `-i` option:

```
egrep -i "steve|fred" friends1 friends2
```

If you want to search for Mike in all files whose names start with "friend*":

```
grep Mike friend*
```

Comment: I am searching for a filename not necessary a pattern inside a file

Comment: Might help adding the `-h` option to show the filename.

Comment: @fedorqui `-H` on a Mac !

Comment: I like the addition of examples. Taking 2nd further, If I want to find files with name "filepattern" inside the current and subdirectories then?

Comment: Great find . -type f -name "pattern" -print was what I was looking for. That helped but still wondering what is wrong with the grep example as mentioned in that article. Is it the Mac Terminal?

Comment: No, not the Mac terminal. In general, grep looks at the CONTENTS of files, rather than at their NAMES. If you want it to look at NAMES, you need to send it a stream of filenames, which you can do by typing `ls | grep something` or `find . -type f | grep something`. Notice in my examples I am not supplying a filename after the grep command.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to exclude "is a directory" stderr stuff from grep, use grep -s.

Comment: That just hid the response but no directory was found

Comment: This worked for me.  From the 'man grep' page: 

-s, --no-messages
             Silent mode.  Nonexistent and unreadable files are ignored (i.e.
             their error messages are suppressed).

Comment: this is not the answer as it does not search the sub-folders, it just looks like it hides the error. On Linux the command will recursive search all sub folders, but mac gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

The clou is the "type-Primary"

so

```
find . -type f -iname "pattern" -print
```

shows you "only" regular files. For other types, see below :

```
-type t : True if the file is of the specified type.  Possible file types are as follows:

b  block special
c  character special
d  directory
f  regular file
l  symbolic link
p  FIFO
s  socket
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add -r to specify its a recursive search, so

```
grep -r searchingforfile /Users/myuser/path/to/dir
```